Calculation of Minkowski dimension
currently I am checking Christopher Bisphops books on fractals in probability theory and he asks to calculate the Minkowski dimension of $E_{\alpha} = \{0\} \cup \{1/n^{\alpha}\}$ for $\alpha > 0$ (Exercise 1.3). I am not able to perform this task directly so I am interested in the case when $\alpha =2$.
Question: It seems one can more or less copy the same case $\alpha=1$?
Proof: The proof goes as follows.

Split the set: $E_{\alpha} = \{0,\dots,1/(n-1)^2\} \cup \{1/n^2,\dots,1\}$ where the latter interval contains $n$-distinct points.
For arbitary $\epsilon > 0$ one can find $n \in \mathbb N$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{(n-1)^2} < \epsilon \leq \frac{1}{n^2},
$$
then since one has for each $n \in \mathbb N$
$$
\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}-\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{2n-1}{n^2(n-1)^2} > \frac{1}{n^2},
$$
Now we can cover the letter interval by $n$-disjoint intervals while covering $[0,1/(n+1)^2]$ by $1$ interval but then one has
$$
\epsilon^{-1/2} \leq N(E_{2},\epsilon) \leq \epsilon^{-1/2}+1,
$$
and thus $dim_{\mathcal{M}}(E_{2})=\frac{1}{2}$.

Although I am not sure about the last part it seems that one should essentially get again an $\epsilon^{-1/2}$ (up to constant) and then the dimension should not change.
